# Device stuck in bootloop after enabling ART

Tags: dalvik, htc-explorer, art

I activated the Android Runtime (ART) instead of Dalvik and after that my phone rebooted but it seems that it's stuck in a bootloop.

Will the first bot after choosing ART take some extra time? How can I tell if it's stuck in a bootloop rather than just booting slowly?

My device is an HTC Explorer running CM 11 beta 4 build.

Comment: Try to wipe the cache partition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moto E Not Starting Properly After Changing runtime to ART](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75346/moto-e-not-starting-properly-after-changing-runtime-to-art)

Answer (score 1):

The first boot after swapping to ART generally takes a little longer to boot. After that it then recompiles every app using the new runtime before you can actually use the device. During this stage the device actually displays a message with it's current progress. If it never gets to that stage then there is a decent chance that Android is stuck trying to boot.

If it's stuck in a bootloop, you should see your phone continually swap from the HTC boot logo to the CM boot logo and back again. If it's stuck on just the CM boot logo then there is a chance that it is actually booting and just taking a long time.

Comment: it's stuck in CM logo but

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below:

1. `adb pull /data/property/persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib`
2. Open the file and replace the `libart.so` with `libdvm.so`.
3. `adb push persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib  /data/property/`.
4. Reboot your device.

Source: [Phone in boot loop after turning on ART (didn't completely uninstall XPosed)](http://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/218wgj/phone_in_boot_loop_after_turning_on_art_didnt/cgars3m).

Comment: Not everyone can understand these commands. Please mention ([edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/108456/edit)) what each of these steps does and the reason they should be followed. That said, this does not answers this : *How can I tell if it's stuck in a bootloop rather than just booting slowly?* Not to mention,  the answer assumes that  `adb` is already enabled in Developer Settings which OP didn't mention at all.

Comment: @Firelord You should understand this if you tried to change Dalvik to ART in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using your device but doing a quick search i found this:

> Before using ART, you have to enable expanding memory in Settings ->
>   Extras!

You might want to do that before enabling ART next time.
You can get more infos on 
[here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2535682)

Answer (score 0):

Try draining the battery, then put it on a charger and try to boot. The same thing happened here on a Motorola Moto G 2nd generation.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing. As the memory space was less in my Moto e, it went to boot loop. First it showed around 169 apps installation figure but after completing that it showed lower nos. in successive boots. After a while when I rebooted it forcefully many times, it started but now with lesser space remaining than Dalvik.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is old, but this may help others in the same situation. My mobile is a LG G2 Mini (D618) rooted with Kingo. After I changed it from Dalvik to ART, it took a long time to reboot, while optimizing all the apps. But then, when the UI showed up, I couldn't do anything because several error messages appeared in sequence. After a while touching OK for each message, the mobile would reboot and start it all over again. In fact it rebooted even if left alone.

I re-flashed it with the stock ROM (with the no-data-loss option) but nothing changed other than it becoming unrooted again. Also tried to access it with an ADB Shell but I kept getting an authorization error. Then, after rebooting it around 30 times, it reverted back to Dalvik by itself, and everything was fine again!