# Moto E is not switching on after changing runtime to ART

Tags: boot, unbricking, art, motorola-moto-e

I changed the runtime option from Dalvik to ART. It asked for a restart.

When I did the restart, Moto E has been stuck in boot time.

When I hold the power button for sometime, it starts again.

It is stuck at a point where Motorola 'M' symbol comes and the footer says "powered by ANDROID".

Please help, I am not able to switch on my Moto E.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moto E Not Starting Properly After Changing runtime to ART](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75346/moto-e-not-starting-properly-after-changing-runtime-to-art) Not *exactly* the same, but helpful hopefully. It seems you have 2 options 1) Factory reset from recovery (nuclear option), 2) Use ADB and try to change the runtime back to dalvik manually! The important part in ADB is `adb shell 'echo libdvm.so >/data/property/persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib'`

Comment: @RossC Can you please tell me the procedure. I am a beginner to this android field. I am just a user of android device. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to change the device back to Dalvik. **However**, you will need to have had **USB Debugging** enabled. If you can't do the below, a factory reset may be your only option.

> **Android Debug Bridge (ADB)**
>   A prgram made by Google for Programmers and developers. Its based on command line and basically communicates with your Android to respond to certain commands.

Setting up ADB

Pre Requirements:-

PC
[Java Runtime environment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jre-7-download-432155.html) or [Java Development kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
Your Device Drivers
An Android Device

USB Debugging MUST be turned ON in the device for ADB to see it.

If you are having trouble completing Pre-Requisites, there are several guides featuring them.

1. First  [Download Android SDK.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. There may be any compressed zip file or exe file
   If zip file, then extract it to C:\android-sdk
   If exe file then double click on it and install it in C:\ Drive(or any other drive you want)
3. Now to get adb and other tools, you need to download 'Platform Tools'
   To download them, go to the android-sdk folder and double click on SDK Manager
   It will ask you which package to download? However, it is your choice which package to Download, but here, we will only talk about platform 
   Tools. So, simply tick on Platform Tools and click on install. Once you have done it. Go to the platform-tools folder in the directory where you installed android-sdk. You will find several files there like adb, fastboot, aapt, etc
4. Now, you can backup the whole folder of android-sdk to any external storage that will make you not download package 
   again if you want to. You can have it placed in any computer and run it as it does not require registry to work
5. Now, you are just one step away from using adb. Next step is SKIPPING SETTING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE (If you however want to set environment variables. Click on Show Content)
   You can easily append the sdk platform-tools and tools folder to your systems environmental path variable directly from command line(cmd) by simply issuing one command and performing a system reboot:

   `SETX PATH "%PATH%;SDK_Install_Path\platform-tools;SDK_Install_Path\android-sdk-windows\tools" -m`
   Just replace the "SDK_Install_Path" in the above with the proper path of your SDK installation. Example: C:\android-sdk-windows
6. Type cmd in the search bar. Copy cmd.exe from there. Go to the directory where you have installed android-sdk. Go to platform-tools folder. Paste cmd there, right click on it and in the settings, select Run as Administrator.

**To change back to Dalvik:**

```
adb shell 'echo libdvm.so >/data/property/persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib'
```