# MOTO E 1st Gen From Dalvik to ART : com.android.systemui stop and loop

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, boot-loop, motorola-moto-e, dalvik, art

May I first apologize for my english : non-native speaker, some erratic grammar might happen.

*Si un francophone passe ici, ce sera bien plus facile pour moi ;)*

I'm NOT skilled in android fix, so be patient and please forgive if i ask you more precision to understand what you say !
Some previous questions were on the same problem, but i did not succeed on performing [the solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81411/moto-e-is-not-switching-on-after-changing-runtime-to-art?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [doesn't dare other] for i did not understood it[2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2707841)

I own a Motorola E, 1st Gen, since feb.2015.

- Legal warranty void six weeks ago...
- No root, no boot, no custom rom.
- Kitkat 4.4 (or maybe 4.4.2, can't remember)

In the last weeks, a trouble appeared : i could neither listen or speak to my interlocutor, but by pluging in a wire headset or putting the phone on speaker (the one you shan't but still use while driving). The normal "phone pressed against the ear" did not worked anymore.

The first times, a simple reboot was all it needed to go back to normal.

Since a few days, reboot have no effect.

After an extend search on the internet, i found a solution for the Moto G (2nd gen) that appeared to work perfectly.

**Going from Dalvik to ART, which i did friday (march 10th).**

- 1st reboot, upgrading 150 apps
  => Several error messages stated that XXX app has stopped. Then "com.android.systemui" has stop, and i cannot validate the prompt : once I click "OK", it comes back before i could even read the next error message.
  I can't do anything with the phone.
  ==> Reboot by long hold on POWER
- 2nd reboot, upgrading 39 apps
  => Several messages again, com.android.systemui again
  ==> Reboot by long hold on POWER
- 3rd reboot, the same
- 4th reboot, upgrading 29 apps
- 5th reboot, the same
- 6th reboot, the same
- 7th reboot, upgrading 28 apps.
- xxth reboot, the same ...

Today, After a day's rest and no manipulation, count on upgrading application dropped to 27.
By repetivly pressing "ok" and 'report" when avalaible, i somehow managed to get as far as parameters menu.
Can't scoll in the microscopic time given between two prompt.
However,
-> The phone seems to receive calls (it ringed about an hour ago) but not to show the screen (caller ID, accepting the call, etc.)
-> Afterward, the led flashed again.

The android buttons (back, home, active application list) doesn't show up.

And here i'm stuck !

What i tried :

- A coffee. Did nothing to the phone, but improved my optimism
- Shut it down, let it rest, power it
- Fully charge it
- Make it reboot by a long hold on power button while it was "upgrading 28 apps".
- Pluging it to the computer, to see if it did anything (it didn't)
- Making loud assumption on the engineer's mother honour and weight.
- Go to recovery mode, and let it boot (if i understand well, it's just a normal boot for long inactivity)
- Go to recovery mode, and wipe cache partition
- Tried to do this : [Moto E is not switching on after changing runtime to ART](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81411/moto-e-is-not-switching-on-after-changing-runtime-to-art?noredirect=1&lq=1)
  => I made it up to the 5th step ; but 6th don't work "Not recognized as a command or program" I tried the shell on E:\Programmes\AndroidSDK and E:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools. Neither works.

What should i do now ?

Thanks a lot,

Kaldui.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask why, don't ask me how ... **Android automatically reverted to Dalvik.**

My best guess is : there is an idiotproof security somewhere that revert automatically after to much fails (at least 20) on booting under the new runtime.
Maybe installing the motorola drivers on my computer before repetivly booting in normal and safe mode while the USB cable was plugged had a positive effect.
Maybe the little bug felt that i painfully resolved to fetch the electronic axe (aka hard reset) and flew away ...

It seems that no data was lost.
It's a true relief !

> *If you cross this topic, and face the same trouble, well ... it took me five day of patience, two full charge and discharge of battery,
>   stubborn booting and prompting closing, ten cache wipe, and utter
>   infuriation before everything settled down by itself. Try your luck !*

Kaldui.

PS. To the android engineer : i was mistaken, you weren't making overtime to pay the attorney for your divorce, yo mama is a fine women, she ain't this overweight, and her reputation is of a loving, caring and faithful person. I also own you a beer.